# Azure Data Factory - load Application Insights logs to Data Lake Gen 2

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have Application Insights configured with a retention period for logs of three months and I want to load them using Data Factory pipelines, scheduled daily, to a Data Lake Gen 2 storage.
The purpose of doing this is to not lose data after the retention period passes and to have the data stored for future purposes - Machine Learning and Reporting, mainly.

I am trying to decide what format to use for storing these data, from the many formats available in Data Lake Gen 2, so if anyone has a similar design, any information or reference to documentation would be greater appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, most format of the log files are `.log` files. If we want to keep file type and move them to Data Lake Gen 2, please use [Binary format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary).
[image]

Binary format can help you move all the folder/sub-folder and all the files to other destination.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you, Leon, but App Insights returns a JSON file. For now I am loading App Insights data as daily JSON files in a {AppInsights_Container}\{entity}\{year}\{Month}\{entity}_{yyyy_mm_dd}.JSON structure, where the JSON files are exported daily.

I am still open to better ways to do it - Data Lake Gen 2 has a lot of features, so I think it's easy to miss the best implementation case.

Comment: @Maus, I got it. Since App Insights returns a JSON file , the JSON format is the first choice. But using Binary format can help you move all the folder/sub-folder and all the files to the Data Lake Gen 2. I think the key is what Data Factory can do not the feature in Data Lake Gen 2

Comment: Hi @Maus, do you have any other concerns?